# How I can make variables autocomplete in the PhpStorm 9 for Blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade, phpdoc

I want PHPdoc blocks were considered within the blade template.

PhpStorm 9, Laravel 5.1, blade template file:

```php
<?php
/* @var App\Models\User $user */
?>
...
<?= $user->email ?> <- autocomplete for the word "email" is working
...
{{ $user->email }} <- autocomplete not working
```

I tried different variants:

```
{{
/**
* @var App\Models\User $user
**/
}}
{{ /* @var App\Models\User $user */ }}
...
{{ $user->email }} <- autocomplete not working...
...
In such variant autocomplete works, but only within that block:
{{
/* @var App\Models\User $user */
$user->email
}}
...
{{ $user->email }} <- here does not work again...
```

How to make the autocomplete worked in all blocks for blade templates?

Comment: @hallaji Do not quote almost 2 years-old ticket like that. 1) PhpStorm supports ("recognizes" as you would say) Blade templates -- it can auto-complete blade statements, for example; 2) PhpStorm does not provide actually code completion for blade variables (same story for other templating engines, e.g. Smarty or Handlebars(?)). 3) `laravel-ide-helper` is for PHP code (inside .php files) -- it will not help here alone if blade variables are not available for code completion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment (December 2015) PhpStorm does not support PHPDoc comments in Blade templates using Blade syntax (especially for completing Blade variables).

Please follow these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26501
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25287

---

**UPDATE:**

The aforementioned [WI-26501](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26501) ticket was implemented in 2017 and you can now use PHPDoc comments to declare variables and their types in Blade files.

Be it PHP code blocks:

```php
<?php
/** @var \App\Models\User $user */
/** @var \App\MyService $someService */
?>
```

... or Blade-specific syntax (`@php` ... `@endphp`):

```php
@php /** @var \App\Models\User $user */ @endphp
```

See the following blog post for details: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/02/code-completion-in-laravel-blade-templates/

[image]

Comment: @OzanKurt None of those tickets had any updates since I posted this answer (that can easily be seen by their last touched dates and current status). The only related ticket (linked to those 2 above) that had mention of 139.1069 (WI-25860 -- does not address the actual issue) also had no updates for almost a year. If there would be any updates you would see it either by `State` field or at least last comments. If you want better answer on progress you better ping the corresponding dev in actual ticket(s).

Comment: I'm wondering how is it possible that the template engine of the most popular PHP framework isn't still properly supported by PhpStorm...

Comment: @Moppo 1) Blade instructions are supported. PHPDoc support has nothing to do with Blade instructions/templates itself. 2) Why Symphony (for example) has dedicated plugin that supports framework-specific stuff .. and "the most popular PHP framework" cannot do the same; especially when IDE (PhpStorm) declares itself framework-agnostic (no preferences to any of the frameworks)? 3) Other popular templating languages (Twig/Smarty/etc) are in the same situation. 4) If anything -- better ask such question devs directly (in those tickets) where they can see your question and have a chance to answer.

Answer (score 23):

More or less same answer, just wrapped in a blade directive:

```
 @php /** @var App\Models\User $user */ @endphp
 {{ $user->email }}
```

Comment: If your answer is same as other one's you can edit that answer for improving

Comment: or ```{{ /** @var App\Models\User $user */ }}```

Answer (score 8):

You can now do it like you wanted:

```
<?php
/* @var App\Models\User $user */
?>
...
{{ $user->email }} <- autocomplete working
```

see https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/02/code-completion-in-laravel-blade-templates/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to explicitly define every property you want to use in your template, you can do the following:

First: Declare the properties you want to expose to your template as typed public properties in your controller

```
class CreateAccountController extends Controller
{
    public ?string $foo = null;
```

Second: Use $this in your view values

```
    return view('auth.create_account', [
        'this' => $this,
    ]);
```

Third:  Declare $this at the top of your controller

```
@php /** @var \App\Http\Controllers\Auth\CreateAccountController $this */ @endphp
```

Fourth:  Use $this in your template

```
<div class="card-header">{{ $this->foo }}</div>
```

You can call "$this" anything you want in your view.  $model might be a better term to use.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now this isn't entirely possible due to PHPStorm's lack of support for Blade templates.

This package may be of some use for other Laravel related issues https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper