# Autocompletion in Laravel Blade Files

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm

is there a way to get autocompletion inside Laravel Blade files using PHPStorm?

I am injecting a class in my Controller like this:

```
$taxCalculator = new TaxCalculator($this->type);

return view('sections.bills.index', compact('title', 'taxCalculator'));
```

And I want to use that class inside my blade file like:

```
$taxCalculator->doSomething()
```

What's quite annoying is, that I can't figure out, how to achieve autocompletion inside that blade files.

Things like

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $taxCalculator App\TaxCalculator
 */
?>
```

don't work for me...

Comment: Think this will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131021/how-i-can-make-variables-autocomplete-in-the-phpstorm-9-for-blade-templates

Comment: @MarkDavidson you are right. I searched on SO but did not come to that duplicate question. Thanks for taking effort to find it