# PhpStorm - Make blade recognize (and autocomplete) variables

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

### The problem

I'm working on a project, that has a lot of blade-files. But PhpStorm doesn't seem to play nice, with mixing `<?php ... ?>` and `@php` ... `@endphp`.

As you can see here, PhpStorm says that `$position_link` isn't defined, yet it is just a few lines above (this image serves the purpose of displaying the IDE-warnings/errors):

[image: PhpStorm not recognizing variables]

It's the same problem with `$data`, but as you can see, on line 98, it doesn't complain. Hmm!

### The question

**Ideally:** How do I make PhpStorm understand this code better?
**Next best thing:** How do I hide these warnings?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Blade Plugin

I can see that the plugin called 'Blade' is now bundled with PhpStorm.

### Solution attempt 2: Googled around

I found a bunch of articles about this:

- [Type hinting works within php block but not in blade](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000682090-type-hinting-works-within-php-block-but-not-in-blade).
  **My comment:** I guess this is the same issue. If PhpStorm thinks the variable doesn't exist, then I assume that it can't autocomplete it either. The solution on that article is to open a new issue. Both linked issues [are](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41272?_ga=2.233784286.1520689318.1642081731-1286017623.1633092126) [incomplete](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37741?_ga=2.233784286.1520689318.1642081731-1286017623.1633092126).
- [Make variables autocomplete in the PhpStorm 9 for Blade templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131021/how-i-can-make-variables-autocomplete-in-the-phpstorm-9-for-blade-templates)
  **My comment:** This was 6 years ago. I refuse to believe that nothing has happened on this area since. [The marked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34136451/1766219) is that it isn't supported. [The most upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942550/1766219) is to add this on the line before: `@php /** @var $position_link @endphp`. But it doesn't work. And even if it did - then it will bloat the code immensely.

### Solution attempt 3: `<?php` instead of `@php`

I also tried changing this:

```
@php
  $position_link = 'left';
  if( App\isset_with_value( $data, 'position_link' ) ){
    $position_link = $data->position_link;
  }
@endphp
<div class="links-wrapper" style='text-align: {{ $position_link }};'>
```

with this:

```
<?php
  $position_link = 'left';
  if( App\isset_with_value( $data, 'position_link' ) ){
    $position_link = $data->position_link;
  }
?>
<div class="links-wrapper" style='text-align: {{ $position_link }};'>
```

... But is still shows the error.

### Solution attempt 4: Remove Blade completely

If I just write the whole thing in good ol' PHP, then I get a stylelint error:

[image: stylelint error]

I know this is another problem, which has to be solved in my Stylelint-settings. I figured I'd just show that this isn't a solution (for me) either.

---

### My system specs

- MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2019
- OS: Big Sur, 11.6
- PhpStorm version: 2021.2.2 - PS-212.5284.49

Comment: Sadly it is still not good in this (individual variables) regard. 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26497 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37741 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61490 4) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-64458 ... I was using Presenters for such extra code/logic used in Blade files .. and typehinting variable (class instance) with PHPDoc in `<?php ?>` at the top of the Blade template allows code completion for class properties/methods (e.g. `{{ $someVar-> }}`) -- at least something.

Comment: Right now I may suggest to try **Laravel Idea plugin**. It's a paid one (monthly/yearly subscription) but worth the money. You can use trial of 14 days to see if it can help you here (I've read some comments that it does help (how much -- cannot say as I have not used it myself).

Comment: BTW: I've tried your code sample in a test project and for me it does not highlight the var in ``{{ $positive_link }}` as unresolved. Possibly because it complains on unknown `App\isset_with_value`, undefined `$data` and `->position_link;`... Do you think you can provide a better code sample that will have ALL needed vars/methods available (so it can be used for testing locally)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs, @LazyOne ! Somehow 'there is no solution to this', gives me closure. :-) 
Regarding your question, then if you simply replace `App\isset_with_value( $data, 'position_link' )` with `array_key_exists( 'position_link', $data )`, then it should be more generic (and the functions are very much alike).